# How to specify associated type <Item=...> when calling associated function of a trait?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, type-inference

I have this rust code [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=use%20itertools%3A%3A%7Brepeat_n%2CRepeatN%7D%3B%0A%0Apub%20trait%20MyIterator%3A%20Iterator%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20fill1(elem%3A%20Self%3A%3AItem%2C%20n1%3A%20usize)%20-%3E%20RepeatN%3CSelf%3A%3AItem%3E%0A%20%20%20%20where%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Self%3A%3AItem%3A%20Clone%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20repeat_n(elem%2C%20n1)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20error%5BE0284%5D%3A%20type%20annotations%20needed%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20let%20r%3A%20RepeatN%3Cchar%3E%20%3D%20MyIterator%3A%3Afill1(%27a%27%2C%205)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%20cannot%20infer%20type%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20note%3A%20cannot%20satisfy%20%60%3C_%20as%20Iterator%3E%3A%3AItem%20%3D%3D%20_%60%0A%20%20%20%20let%20r%3A%20RepeatN%3Cchar%3E%20%3D%20MyIterator%3A%3Afill1(%27a%27%2C%205)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20error%5BE0229%5D%3A%20associated%20type%20bindings%20are%20not%20allowed%20here%0A%20%20%20%20let%20r%3A%20RepeatN%3Cchar%3E%20%3D%20MyIterator%3A%3A%3CItem%3Dchar%3E%3A%3Afill1(%27a%27%2C%205)%3B%0A%7D%0A):

```rust
use itertools::{repeat_n,RepeatN};

pub trait MyIterator: Iterator {
    fn fill1(elem: Self::Item, n1: usize) -> RepeatN<Self::Item>
    where
        Self::Item: Clone,
    {
        repeat_n(elem, n1)
    }
}
```

My Problem is that I can't call this method because rustc can't infer the type.

```rust
// error[E0284]: type annotations needed
// let r: RepeatN<char> = MyIterator::fill1('a', 5);
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
// note: cannot satisfy `<_ as Iterator>::Item == _`
let r: RepeatN<char> = MyIterator::fill1('a', 5);
```

I tried this but it doesn't compile:

```
// error[E0229]: associated type bindings are not allowed here
let r: RepeatN<char> = MyIterator::<Item=char>::fill1('a', 5);
```

How can I specify the type of `Item` in this call? Or is a function outside of the trait (like `itertools::repeat_n`) the best way here?

Comment: Since it doesn't use `self`, why did you put `fill1` in a trait? And why not call `repeat_n` directly? Feels like an [x/y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me.

Comment: Well, `MyIterator` has many more methods that take `self` or `&mut self`. I also have `fn fill2(elem: Self::Item, n1: usize, n2: usize) -> RepeatN<RepeatN<Self::Item>> { /*...*/ }`, `fill3` etc.

Comment: The purpose of `MyIterator` is provide lots of utility methods.

Comment: Although it's theoretically possible to have methods that don't take `self` in a trait, they need to be called on a concrete type (e.g. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=23662fc24d6059523f7aadc3ac7f5a09)) because the implementation of the trait for the concrete type could override them. → My advice would be to make them freestanding generic functions like `fn<T: Clone> fill1 (elem: T, n: usize) -> RepeatN<T> { … }`

Comment: Thanks. If you write that comment as an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you haven't implemented the trait for any types, so no `fill1` function actually exists.

If you implement `MyIterator` for some type that implements `Iterator<Item = char>`, for example `std::iter::Empty<char>`, then you'll be able to call `fill1` through that type.

```rust
use std::iter::Empty;
impl MyIterator for Empty<char> {}

fn main() {
    let r: RepeatN<char> = Empty::fill1('a', 5);
}
```

This is, however, pointless. You will note that `Empty` plays no role in the actual function definition - it could have been any iterator. Furthermore there is no sensible generalization of this behavior to other `Self` types. This is why `itertools::repeat_n` is not a member of the `Itertools` trait: it is nonsense as a trait function because it is not a generalization of behavior shared by multiple iterator types.

In Rust, unlike some other languages, not everything has to be a member of a class. If you merely want to put `fill1` and related things in a common *namespace*, simply use a module, which is the most basic unit of code organization.

```rust
mod my_iterator {
    use itertools::{repeat_n, RepeatN};

    fn fill1<T>(elem: T, n1: usize) -> RepeatN<T>
    where
        T: Clone,
    {
        repeat_n(elem, n1)
    }
}
```